# jQuery .hide() select doesn't work in safari

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#filter-sq-ft-min").change(function(){
        $('#filter-sq-ft-max option:first').prop('selected',true);
        $("#filter-sq-ft-max option").hide();
        var maxValue = $(this).val();
        $("#filter-sq-ft-max option[value='"+maxValue+"']").show();
        $("#filter-sq-ft-max option[value='"+maxValue+"']").nextAll().show();

    });
});
```

I want to hide all the smaller options from max select, after the option on the min select was selected.

But it just works on Google Chrome.

Comment: Please include your HTML code. The jquery selector might be empty

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, Safari and IE ignore styling of `<option>` elements. I had the issue and, for me, adding `hidden` attributes as mentioned in another answer didn't work.
So I ended up simply disabling them, which worked for my use case:

```js
$("#filter-sq-ft-min").change(function(){
  $('#filter-sq-ft-max option:first').prop('selected',true);

  $("#filter-sq-ft-max option")
    .hide()
    .attr('disabled', 'disabled');

  var maxValue = $(this).val();

  $("#filter-sq-ft-max option[value='"+maxValue+"']")
    .show()
    .removeAttr('disabled');

  $("#filter-sq-ft-max option[value='"+maxValue+"']")
    .nextAll()
    .show()
    .removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`style="display:none;"` is not a reliable way of hiding `option` elements as browser support is a bit iffy.

in html5, you can add the [hidden attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_hidden.asp) to your `option` element; support for it is very good.

`$("#filter-sq-ft-max option").attr('hidden','');`

`<option hidden>This option is hidden</option>`

Answer (score 0):

Please add optgroup and make it group of options then use disabled attributes to disable optgroup

```html
for hidding 
jQuery('select optgroup[id="addon"]').attr( "disabled", "disabled" ); for mac safari    
jQuery('select optgroup[id="addon"]').prop('disabled', true); //for iphone safari
for showing use
jQuery('optgroup').removeAttr('disabled);
```

Answer (score -3):

The ready event is fired when the DOM is loaded.

Wait for all assets to be loaded like css & images, 
Try this :

```
$(window).load(function() {
    ...
});
```

Comment: I think the answer is ok, but needs bit more explanation.

Comment: He's only operating on the DOM, he doesn't need other assets.